# Making a regex that accepts certain characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make a RegEx in Java and test a word to see if it contain some characters like `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` or `"$"` or `"_"` without the rest of the possible characters including the space.

I tried with :

```
boolean test = Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z||[_]||[$]]",wordTest);
```

or

```
boolean test = Pattern.matches("[a-z]|[A-Z]|\\*|_+",wordTest);
```

so some word like : `"&_bird"` , `"bi_r&"`
  but not `" bird"` , `"b ird^("` for exemple.

It's been few hours that I am looking for a solution on the web but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean test = Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+", wordTest);`